# Have my function keep checking for it's condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that will animate the progress bar I have from 0 to 100 when it is on the screen. The problem is, if it is not visible (not visible on the page) on page load, it will never be triggered.

My code

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $('.dial').knob({
            min: '0',
            max: '100',
            readOnly: true,
            displayInput: true
        });

        $(".dial:in-viewport").parent().show(0, function() {
            $({ value: 0 }).animate(
                { value: 100 },
                {   duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    progress: function() {
                        $('.dial').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My question is how do I make it so that function will constantly check to see if it is on the screen until it returns valid.

Comment: This should be in `document.ready()`, not in a `<script>` node.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 `$(function () { .. });` is `document.ready()`.

Comment: You could use a setInterval call.

Comment: Why would the element not be there on page load? Is there another function which creates these elements? If so, you should execute this code then

Comment: @RGraham I meant that if the element was not on the page on load

Comment: @DrCord Using a setInterval worked well! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create an interval which executes the code every n milliseconds.

```
var interval = 400;
var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    // your code goes here ...
    if (yourCodeHasBeenExecuted === true) {
       window.clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, interval);
```

I guess this will work, but it is not the most beautiful solution existing. A better way would be to use window resize or window scrolling events, depending of what you need, and execute your code there.

You find an example for a resize event [here](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).